# Não consigo alterar o app padrão do react native

Tags: android, react, react-native

Fiz algumas alterações no arquivo index.android.js e salvei, ao rodar comando react-native run-android, o app continua o mesmo!! O código está assim:

```
var React = require('react');
var Text = require('react-native').Text;
var AppRegistry = require('react-native').AppRegistry;

const App = function(){
 return (
   <Text>Meu primeiro app</Text>
 );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app1', function(){ return App });
```

Porém vem aquela mesma mensagem de bem vindo ao react-native!!

Comment: So estou curioso, por que voce nao usa ES6+? De qualquer maneira, podes escrever como gerou o projeto?

Answer (score 1):

Como voce gerou o projeto? Usando `create-react-native-app` ou diretamente com `react-native init`?

a) Projetos gerados com o `create-react-native-app` rodam direto do arquivo `App.js` sem precisar registrar o componente com AppRegistry.

b) Projetos gerados com o `react-native init` tem como ponto de partida o `index.ios.js` ou `index.android.js`

Comment: Foi através do react-native init, eu consegui resolver o problemando atravéz do reload, com o comando R R. Porém ainda não entendo bem porque com o comando react-native run-android não atualiza o app no dispositivo

Comment: Como voce esta rodando o app no dispositivo? Se fosse usando o Expo, ele dava live reload. Agora usando o Android Studio seria outra coisa... Verificou se o Live Reload tava habilitado no menu de desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu problema for relacionado ao *Reload* e se estiver utilizando o **Android Studio** é necessário recarregar a aplicação, com o comando <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (aperta a tecla <kbd>R</kbd> duas vezes) no emulador, você também tem a opção de ativar o *Reload* automático com o comando: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, após isso, aparece esse menu na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem o meu *Reload* automático está ativado!

Após ativar, toda vez que você realizar uma alteração e salvar, automaticamente a aplicação é recarregada no emulador.

Caso você esteja utilizando o Expo, não é necessário ativar.

E por fim, se você estiver utilizando diretamente no celular através da depuração USB, basta chacoalha o celular que aparece o menu para o *Reload.*